# Getting Error while importing functions from a file which takes runtime arguments

Tags: python, import, sys

I have a file Main.py which takea one runtime argument NoOftimes. Which I store in `NoOftimes = sys.argv[1]`
I tried to run help.py for NoOftimes in a function of Main.py but getting error

```
def RunScriptForTime(NoOftimes):
    for i in range(NoOftimes):
        print("File is opened........")
        os.system('python help.py')
        time.sleep(300)
        print("Opening File again.....") 
RunScriptForTime(NoOftimes)
```

**ERROR**

```
File is opened........
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\projects\psx\help.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Main import getCompanyId, getLastId, getNameIdx, isCompanyExist
  File "E:\projects\psx\Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    NoOftimes = int(sys.argv[1])
```

**Note**
I am importing some functions of Main.py in help.py maybe it is because of it require runtime arguments there. Can you spot the error what i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved now. It was because the `Main.py` was run every time the `help.py` was opened.
Use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   NoOfTimes = sys.argv[1]
   RunScriptForTime(NoOfTimes)
   sys.exit()
```

The Main.py will run this block of code only if python script is directly run by user.